# How to make a dialog box size which works in every browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am showing a dialog box, but the dialog box is perfectly showing on my screen. But today I just looked into the dialog box in some another screen which was smaller than my PC screen. Some part of the dialog box got cut from above and below. How I can set the height and width which will work in every browser and on each PC screen?

Comment: Put every dimension on your html in terms of "em", I guess you are using px. em is a relative measure and if it works fine on your pc it should work fine on any other resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used "em" like ganguly-sarthak said, but you should be using percentages if you want it to look the same in all resolutions.

Some reading: *[CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)*.